# How to create a ' Starts on Windows startup ' checkbutton in InstallJammer?

Tags: installation, startup

Using InstallJammer 1.2.15 , how to create a checkbutton that allows (or forgive) the installer to create a shortcut in this folder :

```
C:\Users\<%Username%>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```